# Tandem creaking when captain pedals hard

Tags: drivetrain, noise, tandems

I'm used to single rider bikes, but new to tandems. We have a specific creak that I (as captain) can also feel through the pedals. It's on every strong stroke of the captain's pedals, left or right, but if I take my feet off and let my stoker pedal, it doesn't happen. She also can't feel it reliably through the pedals when I cause it. But she is only about 1/3 my weight  (also 1/5 my age, and inexperienced).

The bike has an eccentric front BB, and the creaking started a few tens of km after I had to change the front crankset (the previous owner is not to be trusted with screw threads). I've already made sure the cranks and pedals are on tight. I plan to check the chainring bolts, but could the BB cause this? Is there something else tandem-specific I should look at while I'm at it?

Comment: Is the frame intact?  The one time I had a persistent creaking sound when pedalling that I couldn't track down to any problem with the cranks or BB, it turned out that there was a crack growing across the down tube.

Comment: @DavidW I can't see any sign of damage, and it hasn't had any hard use in the few months I've had it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did turn out to be (almost) tandem-specific: the eccentric bottom bracket was moving slightly even though the bolts securing it seemed tight (when tested with a multi-tool).

This model uses two M8 bolts into the underside of the BB housing on the frame (not a Thorn  but a similar design). Other designs use a wedge. The left bolt was holding but the right allowed a fraction of a millimetre of play. I adjusted the chain tension slightly at the same time so the bolts are now clamping onto a different bit of the BB shell. I didn't remove the cranks so haven't inspected the BB itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching something damping to the keel tube and see if that changes things.  The keel runs between both bottom brackets and can function as a resonance amplifier because it has vibrations at both ends.

As a test, temporarily wrap on some scrap cloth rags with some tape to stop them sliding back.  If that helps, there are more elegant solutions like that stick-on foam used in cars for noise damping - a strip of that down the underside might be all it needs.

Comment: I'm wary of damping things until I've ruled out a real cause, so I was keeping this in reserve. But I got the chance to look at it in good light, and I'm pretty certain I've caught it